# Setting negative margin doesn't work on Android

Tags: java, android, margin

I'm creating a list of `ImageView` in my android app with negative margins set for each.
I'm using this to convert dp to pixels:

```
public int dpToPixel(float dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int)((dp * displayMetrics.density) + 0.5);
}
```

And the List is like this:

```
List<GridLayout> columnNLinesGrid = new ArrayList<GridLayout>();
List<ImageView> columnLines = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

for (int i = 1; i <= rowLayoutsCount; i++) {

    columnNLinesGrid.add(new GridLayout(this));
    GridLayout.LayoutParams colGridParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    colGridParam.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
    colGridParam.topMargin = dpToPixel(-10);
    columnNLinesGrid.get(i - 1).setLayoutParams(colGridParam);
    columnNLinesGrid.get(i - 1).setColumnCount(columnLayoutsCount);
    linearLayouts.get(i - 1).addView(columnNLinesGrid.get(i - 1));

    for (int j = 1; j <= columnLayoutsCount; j++) {
         columnLines.add(new ImageView(this));
         GridLayout.LayoutParams lineParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
         lineParam.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
         lineParam.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(j - 1);
         if(j-1>0){
             lineParam.leftMargin = (int) dpToPixel(23);
         } else{
             lineParam.leftMargin = 0;
         }
         lineParam.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
         lineParam.height = (int) dpToPixel(35);
         columnLines.get(colLinesCount).setLayoutParams(lineParam);
         columnLines.get(colLinesCount).setImageResource(R.drawable.linevert);
         columnNLinesGrid.get(i - 1).addView(columnLines.get(colLinesCount));
         colLinesCount++;
    }
}
```

It seems like `colGridParam.topMargin = dpToPixel(-10)` is not working. I tried negative margins in some other cases and neither of them worked.

Comment: Update: I tried a positive margin but it didn't work!

Comment: Update 2: Margins DO work on API 25 and later!!!